# Class number upper bound for imaginary quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

For real quadratic fields, there is the bound
$$h\leq \lfloor\sqrt{\Delta}/2\rfloor$$

Is there anything similar for imaginary quadratic fields? More generally, I'm interested in a bound for $h$ involving the discriminant of the number field.

Comment: For the imaginary quadratic field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$, the [class number formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_number_formula#Dirichlet_class_number_formula) implies that $h \ll \sqrt{d} L(1,\chi_{-d})$; and the estimate $L(1,\chi_{-d}) \ll \log d$ is a standard bound in analytic number theory. Both can be given with explicit constants with enough work.