# Explicit Upper Bound for Class Number of Quadratic Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to find an explicit upper bound bound (explicit => without big O or small o notation, and with explicitly calculated constants) for the class number of a quadratic field.

So far, I've found that It was Littlewood who first addressed the question of how large the class number $h$ of an imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ can be as a function of $|d|$ as $d \rightarrow$ $-\infty$ through fundamental discriminants. In 1927  he showed, assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis (GRH), that for all fundamental $d<0$
$$
h \leq 2(c+\mathrm{o}(1))|d|^{\frac{1}{2}} \log \log |d|,
$$
where $c=e^\gamma / \pi$, where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Is there any way to get rid of the $o(1)$ in this expression? Or is there a more explicit bound available somewhere?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887252/class-number-upper-bound-for-imaginary-quadratic-fields).

Comment: That post does not answer my question. There's a single comment which says that "with enough effort" we can prove that $L(1 - \chi_D) << \log(D)$ but there is no motivation, no source and there are no steps!. I'd be very grateful if you could expand upon the comment left in that post